# Global extremum on an open interval

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

If a function is continuous on an open interval, and at a given point its first derivative is zero and the second derivative is zero, is that point an absolute max/min? Should the first derivative be zero and second derivative be non-zero at a point where the absolute max/min exists, and vice versa?

Comment: If you look at, for example $f(x)=x^3$, you can see that at $x=0$ both the first and second derivatives are zero, and there is no minimum or maximum. On the other hand, $g(x)=x^2$ does have a minimum at $x=0$.

Comment: Or look at $g(x)=x^4$: at $x=0$ both the first and second derivatives are zero, and there is a minimum

Comment: For the first question, it may or may not be, which is why the Second Derivative Test is inconclusive when that's the case. For example, for both $f(x) = x^3$ and $f(x) = x^4$, $f''(x) = 0$ at $x = 0$. However, for the former, it's just an inflection point, while for the latter, it's a global minimum. For the second question, no, $f''(x)$ can certainly be $0$, as shown by $f(x) = x^4$. However, if you want to use the second derivative in order to determine whether the critical point is an extreme point (and its type), then you want $f''(x)$ to be non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it's obvious that equating 1st derivative to zero is inconclusive for finding the extrema. It is a necessary condition for there to be an extrema, but it is not always there, that is, an extremum will always have 1st derivative zero but not all points with zero first derivative are max/min. Inflection points, undulation points etc come into the picture.

The main thing to observe with second derivatives considering extrema is that the sign remains same in the vicinity of an extremum (this is so because the curvature remains same). It may or may not be zero but if the sign remains unchanged, then it is an extremum. For if it happens otherwise, then it may be an inflection point etc. You can try this with examples.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily it is maximum or minimum for details please check the link https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/maximum-and-minimum-of-a-function/

Comment: Not only point of inflection also for a function like f(X)=!X!   ( Modlus of  X ) . X=0 is point of local minimum and function is continuous at X= 0 but still non differentiable at X= 0 .